# How to generalize matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

Consider expression $x^T A x$, where $x$ is a vector of size $5 \times 1$ and $A$ is a matrix of size $5 \times 5$. The result of the expression will be a constant.

Now, how to generalize this expression, so a vector of constants of size $n \times 1$ is computed for $x$ being a matrix $5 \times n$.

If the formula is not changed then the result is a matrix of size $n \times n$, which is of course not the desired answer.

The solution can be the following `sum(x'*A .* x', 2)`.

Question: Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: What is the desired answer? What is the solution? There's no context here.

Comment: I think beginner wants to know what is the right form to do the operation $x^T A x$ "$n$ times at once" for $x$ being an array of $n$ $5 \times 1$ vectors.

Comment: You may want to make $x$ a $1 \times 5 \times n$ 3d array in matlab? Then your result will be a $1 \times 1 \times n$ 3d array, I think.

Comment: You need the diagonal entries of $x^TAx$. Your approach calculates these diagonal entries without having to calculate the whole matrix, which I think is already pretty good. The only thing is, I believe it should be sum(x'*A.*x',2), right?

Comment: @PedroMilet Yes, thanks.